# How to keep the text of a UILabel inside the safeArea?

Tags: swift, xcode, uilabel, uiedgeinsets

I've created a custom UILabel in order to be able to change its safe area so the text could have some padding and look nicer, but after I changed my safeArea the text still go all the way from edge to edge and no padding added here's my code

```
class customLabel: UILabel {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setUp()

    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }



    override var safeAreaInsets: UIEdgeInsets {
        return UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10)
    }


    func setUp(){
        lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping
        numberOfLines = 0
        textColor = UIColor.white
        textAlignment = .center
        layer.cornerRadius = 8
        clipsToBounds = true
        backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.7)
        font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 20)
        translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    }

}
```

how to keep the text inside the new safeAreaInset?

thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`safeAreaInsets` shouldn't be used for text padding. Safe Area was added to prevent covering `UIView`'s content by navigation bars, tab bars, toolbars etc. So you can override this variable in `UIView` subclasses to make it's subviews visible when you add constraints to `UIView`'s Safe Area. But since text in `UILabel` doesn't have constraints to Safe Area so overriding this variable doesn't make any sense.

Instead you need to override [textRect(forBounds:limitedToNumberOfLines:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uilabel/1620545-textrect) method of `UILabel`.

```
override func textRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect, limitedToNumberOfLines numberOfLines: Int) -> CGRect {
    return bounds.insetBy(dx: 10, dy: 10)
}
```

`insetBy(dx:dy:)` method returns the rectangle with left and right insets from `dx` and top and bottom insets from `dy`.